# Compactly supported $C^2$ Function

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm studying PDE's and the course is taught in many analysis languages which I am not familiar with.

Here are some statements that bother me from my tutor:

given $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ compactly supported, we have the following facts:

- $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \exists$ $0 < M < \infty$
  s.t. $|\frac{\partial{f(x-y)}}{\partial{x_i}}|\leq M$, $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n$
- $\forall  x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \exists $ $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, s.t. $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \Omega, \forall h \in (0, 1]$ we have $$f(x+he_i-y) - f(x-y) = 0$$
  (this reminds me of Rolle's Theorem but I don't know if it fits here)

*note:* $e_i$ is n-dimensional with only the i-th entry being $1$ and the other $0$s

Could you kindly guide me based on the definition of the compactly supported $C^2$ function? Those facts seem to be quite obvious and my tutor just writes it down to me, but as stated above I am not fully getting it. I did some Googling, some loose concepts are built up but I cannot connect them quite well.

Comment: Since $f$ is compactly supported, for fixed $x$ the function $y\mapsto\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x-y)$ will also be compactly supported and hence bounded by continuity. For the second point there seem to be some assumptions on $\Omega$ missing because we can always take $\Omega=\Bbb R^n$ so that the rest will be vacuously true.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt comment! I don't think there are more assumptions on $\Omega$ but it is from the poisson's equation $-\Delta u = f$ if it helps